# asp.net mvc, unordered list scroll to bottom on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, scroll, postback

Everytime li is added to the ul , the scroll stays at the same place, how to move scroll always to the bottom of ul on postback to show latest items?

```
  <ul id="discussion"></ul>



 <script>
    var usrName = "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name";
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            $('#discussion').append('<li style="left:5%"><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };
        $('#displayname').val(usrName);
        $('#message').focus();
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }
</script>
```

Solution by Andrew Walters

```
            //  function that the hub call back to display messages.
             chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Adds message
            $('#discussion').append('<li style="left:5%"><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            //scrolls down after item is added
            $("#discussion").scrollTop($("#discussion")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Comment: Viktor, this is not `Classic ASP` it's `ASP.NET` - could you replace the tag, please?

Comment: Thank you for noticing, when I've typed asp.net somehow it auto corrected and chose classic, changed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to re-scroll after each item is added.

```
$("#discussion").scrollTop($("#discussion")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4etXb/2/